# How to design a database table structure for storing and retrieving search statistics?

Tags: sql, search, statistics

I'm developing a website with a custom search function and I want to collect statistics on what the users search for.

It is not a full text search of the website content, but rather a search for companies with search modes like:

- by company name
- by area code
- by provided services
- ...

How to design the database for storing statistics about the searches?
What information is most relevant and how should I query for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's dependent on how the different search modes work, but generally I would say that a table with 3 columns would work:

```
SearchType    SearchValue    Count
```

Whenever someone does a search, say they search for "Company Name: Initech", first query to see if there are any rows in the table with SearchType = "Company Name" (or whatever enum/id value you've given this search type) and SearchValue = "Initech". If there is already a row for this, UPDATE the row by incrementing the Count column. If there is not already a row for this search, insert a new one with a Count of 1.

By doing this, you'll have a fair amount of flexibility for querying it later. You can figure out what the most popular searches for each type are:

```
... ORDER BY Count DESC WHERE SearchType = 'Some Search Type'
```

You can figure out the most popular search types:

```
... GROUP BY SearchType ORDER BY SUM(Count) DESC
```

Etc.

Comment: that was my design too. I was wondering if there are any kind of a WWGD (what would google do?) stlye additions to that design. Or some clever tricks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty general question but here's what I would do:

**Option 1**
If you want to strictly separate all three search types, then create a table for each.  For company name, you could simply store the CompanyID (assuming your website is maintaining a list of companies) and a search count.  For area code, store the area code and a search count.  If the area code doesn't exist, insert it.  Provided services is most dependent on your setup.  The most general way would be to store key words and a search count, again inserting if not already there.

Optionally, you could store search date information as well.  As an example, you'd have a table with Provided Services Keyword and a unique ID.  You'd have another table with an FK to that ID and a SearchDate.  That way you could make sense of the data over time while minimizing storage.

**Option 2**
Treat all searches the same.  One table with a Keyword column and a count column, incorporating SearchDate if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-starter-schemas.aspx